# Can a Time Capsule join a third-party Wi-Fi router as a client, and still bridge traffic to/from its Ethernet port

Tags: wireless-networking, router, time-machine

Can an Apple Time Capsule join a third-party Wi-Fi router as a client, and still bridge traffic to/from its Ethernet port?

Maybe same question but can a Time Capsule 1TB use a LAN printer? So it doesn't have to use the internet.

I this possible?

So Wi-Fi modem/router (Cisco) ------Wi-Fi----TC-----Ethernet LAN printer

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're looking for is known in the industry as "Proxy STA". The AirPort Express with 802.11n supports this, but the Time Capsule does not.